# How to catch errors (Smartsheet API Python SDK)

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api

I am missing fundamental knowledge. 
How to 'properly' catch errors returned by the API.

I'm using Python 3.+

If I pass in the wrong sheet ID

```
        try:
            update_sht = SmSh.Sheets.get_sheet(dd_id)
            print("OK?:", update_sht, flush=True)
        except:
            print("Error Print:\n", update_sht)
```

I get this response (in the IPython console)

```
Response: {
status: 404 Not Found
content: {
{
    "errorCode": 1006,
    "message": "Not Found",
    "refId": "jod4cgoou0sw"
}
}
OK?: {"result": {"code": 1006, "errorCode": 1006, "message": "Not Found",
"name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the
problem. ", "refId": "jod4cgoou0sw", "shouldRetry": false, 
"statusCode": 404}}
```

and while it returns an error response, it isn't an exception according to try/except.

At this point, I would like to exit out of the loop I am in, instead of continuing on until I get to other lines of code like this

```
        for col in update_sht.columns:
```

that DO give errors that cause the program to fail.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-195-85dde6ec7071>", line 1, in <module>
    xxx(debug=False)

  File "<ipython-input-194-0b889c817b08>", line 75, in xxx
    for col in update_sht.columns:

AttributeError: 'Error' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I'm doing more than one thing on the sheet, if I find it, and would prefer not to have a try/except around error line of code (I exaggerate) unless I need them for other errors.

I know/hope this is easier than I have been trying to make it, but as I opened with, I am missing something fundamental.

-Craig

---- UPDATE ----
I am going around in circles.

If errors_as_exceptions is true, then this

```
update_sht = SmSh.Sheets.get_sheet(dd_id)
```

raises and exception, but

```
print(update_sht)
```

or anything similar shows the previous good value in the object.
How do I determine the status code and error codes so I can take appropriate action?
Nothing I have tried has worked.

If errors_as_exceptions is false, then this

```
update_sht = SmSh.Sheets.get_sheet(dd_id)
    print(update_sht.result.code)
```

gives me the error code, but only when there is an error ... so I need to catch the error that occurs when there is no
error.

If I raise the error (errors_as_exceptions=True), how do I determine the status code and error code and if I don't raise the error, 
how do I do the same?
I want to prevent my code from failing and give the user useful information on what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `ss.errors_as_exceptions()` and your code looks something like this

```
try:
    my_sheet = ss.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_ID)
    print(my_sheet)
except Exception as e: 
    print(e.message)
```

The result will look something like this `1006: Not Found`. So, the exception message appears to be `errorCode:message`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. That moves me closer.

Comment: The piece I am still missing is
    print(e)

gives this result
    {"result": {"code": 1006, "errorCode": 1006, "message": "Not Found", "name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "refId": "6mcsl5qrlpw8", "shouldRetry": false, "statusCode": 404}}

and I haven't groked the relationship from that to e.message.

The return value looks (to me) like a dictionary with one item -- a dictionary. But when I try to use it like a dictionary, I get

    AttributeError: 'ApiError' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: The base class for all exceptions raised by the SDK is SmartsheetException. From there determine what the exception instance type is using an isinstance test (ApiError and HttpError are two most common). ApiError contains an error property which contains an result property with API error details. Code something like:

    sheet_ID = 1234
    try:
        my_sheet = ss.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_ID)
        print(my_sheet)
    except SmartsheetException as e:
        if isinstance(e, ApiError):
            print(e.error.result.error_code)
            print(e.error.result.message)

Comment: Thanks to Tim's explanation, I've updated the Gist to reflect what he's saying in his comment above. This code can be found here:  https://gist.github.com/stmcallister/59560902ddd9b1abeb5056dee6a0f8f9

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Python SDK to raise exceptions for API errors call the errors_as_exceptions method on the client object, e.g.

```
ss = smartsheet.Smartsheet()
ss.errors_as_exceptions()
```