# Smartsheet API in Python: how to access response data from client

Tags: python, python-requests, smartsheet-api

I am trying to understand / plan for the rate limits, particularly for the get_cell_history method in the python api.

When I run the code below, I see the following response printed to my console:

```
{"response": {"statusCode": 429, "reason": "Too Many Requests", "content": {"errorCode": 4003, "message": "Rate limit exceeded.", "refId": "SOME_REF_ID"}}}
```

But I am tyring to force my if statement to read the response and check for the 429 status code

```
import smartsheet

smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet('My_API_KEY')
smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions(True)

sheet_id = 'My_Sheet_ID'
edit_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)  # type: smartsheet.smartsheet.models.Sheet

for row in edit_sheet.rows:  # type: smartsheet.smartsheet.models.Row
    for cell in row.cells:  # type: smartsheet.smartsheet.models.Cell
        cell_history = smartsheet_client.Cells.get_cell_history(sheet_id, row.id, cell.column_id,
                                                                include_all=True)
        if cell_history.request_response.status_code == 429:
            print(f'Rate limit exceeded.')
        elif cell_history.request_response.status_code == 200:
            print(f'Found Cell History: {len(cell_history.data)} edits')
```

Where can I access this response? Why does my program run without printing out the "Rate limit exceeded" string?

I am using Python 3.8 and the package smartsheet-python-sdk==2.105.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code shows how to successfully catch an API error when using the Smartsheet Python SDK. For simplicity, I've just used the `Get Sheet` operation and handled the error with status code `404` in this example, but you should be able to implement the same approach in your code. Note that you need to include the `smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions()` line (as shown in this example) so that Smartsheet errors get raised as exceptions.

```
# raise Smartsheet errors as exceptions
smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions()

try:
    # call the Get Sheet operation
    # if the request is successful, my_sheet contains the Sheet object
    my_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(4183817838716804) 
except smartsheet.exceptions.SmartsheetException as e:
    # handle the API error
    if isinstance(e, smartsheet.exceptions.ApiError):
        if (e.error.result.status_code == 404):
            print(f'Sheet not found.')
        else:
            print(f'Another type of error occurred: ' + str(e.error.result.status_code))
```

Finally, here's a bit of additional info about error handling with the Smartsheet Python SDK that may be helpful (from [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078622/how-to-catch-errors-smartsheet-api-python-sdk)).

- `SmartsheetException` is the base class for all of the exceptions raised by the SDK. The two most common types of `SmartsheetException` are `ApiError` and `HttpError`. After trapping the exception, first determine the exception type using an `isinstance` test.
- The `ApiError` exception has an `Error` class object accessible through the `error` property, and then that in turn points to an `ErrorResult` class accessible through the `result` property.
- The details of the API error are stored in that `ErrorResult`.
- Note that to make the Python SDK raise exceptions for API errors, you must call the `errors_as_exceptions()` method on the client object.

**---------------------**

**UPDATE (retry logic):**

To repro the behavior you've described in your first comment below, I used (most of) the code from your original post above, and added some print statements to it. My code is as follows:

```
# raise Smartsheet errors as exceptions
smartsheet_client.errors_as_exceptions()

sheet_id = 5551639177258884
edit_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)  # type: smartsheet.smartsheet.models.Sheet

# initialize ctr
row_ctr = 0

for row in edit_sheet.rows:  # type: smartsheet.smartsheet.models.Row
    row_ctr += 1
    print('----ROW # ' + str(row_ctr) + '----')
    cell_ctr = 0
    for cell in row.cells:  # type: smartsheet.smartsheet.models.Cell
        cell_ctr += 1
        try:
            cell_history = smartsheet_client.Cells.get_cell_history(sheet_id, row.id, cell.column_id, include_all=True)
            print(f'FOUND CELL HISTORY: {len(cell_history.data)} edits [cell #' + str(cell_ctr) + ' ... rowID|columnID= ' + str(row.id) + '|' + str(cell.column_id) + ']')
        except smartsheet.exceptions.SmartsheetException as e:
            # handle the exception
            if isinstance(e, smartsheet.exceptions.ApiError):
                if (e.error.result.status_code == 429):
                    print(f'RATE LIMIT EXCEEDED! [cell #' + str(cell_ctr) + ']')
```

Interestingly, it seems that the Smartsheet Python SDK has built-in ***retry logic** (with exponential backoff)*. The exception handling portion of my code isn't ever reached -- because the SDK is recognizing the Rate Limiting error and automatically retrying (with exponential backoff) any requests that fail with that error, instead of raising an exception for my code to catch.

I can see this happening in my print output. For example, here's the cell history output from Row #2 in my sheet (each row has 8 columns / cells) -- where all `Get Cell History` calls were processed without any exceptions being thrown.

[image: row #2 output]

Things continue without error until the 7th row is being processed, when a Rate Limiting error occurs when it's trying to get cell history for the fifth column/cell in that row. Instead of this being a fatal error though -- I see processing pause for a few seconds (i.e., no additional output is printed to my console for a few seconds)...and then processing resumes. Another Rate Limiting error occurs, followed by a slightly longer pause in processing, after which processing resumes and cell history is successfully retrieved for the fifth through eighth cells in that row.

[image: row #7 output]

As my program continues to run, I see this same thing happen several times -- i.e., several API calls are successfully issued, then a Rate Limiting error occurs, processing pauses momentarily, and then processing resumes with API calls successfully issued, until another Rate Limiting error occurs, etc. etc. etc.

To confirm that the SDK is automatically retrying requests that fail with the Rate Limiting error, I dug into the code a bit. Sure enough, I see that the `request_with_retry` function within `/smartsheet/smartsheet.py` does indeed include logic to retry failing requests with exponential backoff (*if `should_retry` is true*).

[image: request_with_retry]

Which begs the question, how does `should_retry` get set (i.e., in response to which error codes will the SDK automatically retry a failing request)? Once again, the answer is found within `/smartsheet/smartsheet.py` (SDK source code). This suggests that you don't need exception handling logic in your code for the Rate Limiting error (or for any of the other 3 errors where `should_retry` is set to `True`), as the SDK is built to automatically retry any requests that fail with that error.

[image: error codes to retry]

Comment: The exception handling you described does eventually catch the rate limit exception.  However, before the exception is caught, I see `{"response": {"statusCode": 429, "reason": "Too Many Requests", "content": {"errorCode": 4003, "message": "Rate limit exceeded.", "refId": "SOME_REF_ID"}}}` printed to the console many times without triggering the exception. I am confused by this behavior and I don't know what is happening behind the scenes. Is the request that caused this message to print retried? Where in the client would I see the message being printed?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info. TLDR; the SDK automatically retries (with exponential backoff) any requests that fail with the Rate Limiting error. If this sufficiently addresses your original question/post, please mark the answer as Accepted so that others will be more likely to benefit from this info in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I did poke around in the source code and threw my hands up when I saw the comments in the `native` method of the `class OperationErrorResult(object)`:         """
        Sadly, we won't be returning what was expected.

        Args:
            expected (list): Dashed expectations
        """

Comment: In all earnestness, thank you for providing your analysis and taking the time for your thoughtful exposition.  It helped me understand the issue and how to progress through this issue.  I appreciate your efforts and I am grateful that you looked into this.

Comment: Glad to help, Ian! Always nice when someone finds my feedback useful, and even better when I learn something new along the way (like I did today about the Smartsheet Python SDK having automatic retry logic for specific errors).